# Can I use TaskScheduler.Default with Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, task, scheduled-tasks

I can use `TaskScheduler.Default` with `Task.Factory.StartNew` like this,

```
 await Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => { /* to do what you need */ }, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Is there a way I can use `TaskScheduler.Default` with `Task.Run` something like ?

```
await Task.Run(
() => { /* to do what you need */ }, 
CancellationToken.None, 
TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: It's the *default* so it's the one [already used by Task.Run](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,5614). You don't need to provide any of those options - just `await Task.Run(()=>code)`. What's the actual problem? Why are you trying to pass the scheduler and cancellation token like this? Did you encounter a blocking issue perhaps?

Comment: BTW even with `Task.Factory.StartNew` you didn't have to pass those defaults. Just `wait Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* to do what you need */ })` would work the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, the default task scheduler for `StartNew` is not `TaskScheduler.Default`. It's `TaskScheduler.Current`, which IMO is very unexpected and can cause surprising behavior in some situations.